# Select from tuple with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working through a course, and the current challenge is to "Write a function that takes an array of names and ages, then returns only the names."

So far my approach has looked like this:

```
function names(arr: [string, number]) {
  let result: [] = [];
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    if (typeof(element) === "string") {
      result.push(element);
    }
  })
  return result;
}
```

I'm trying to get tests to pass that assert that I am actually getting just the strings returned from my function.  I'm at a loss, the current error I'm getting from my attempt at a solution is

```
names([['Amir', 34], ['Betty', 17]])

Expected: ['Amir', 'Betty'] but got: type error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your test look like?

Comment: Uh, your input is an array of arrays.  Not an array of a string and number

Comment: you need to get the first parameter of the element like: element[0] === "string"

Comment: What specifically does "an array of names and ages" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to define

```
let result: [] = [];
```

as

```
let result: string[] = [];
```

Also looks like your parameter is an array of arrays. So you need to define

```
arr: [string, number]
```

as

```
arr: [string, number][]
```

or equivalent syntax is

```
arr: Array<[string, number]>
```

and then change you for loop as well. Something like that.

```
function names(arr: [string, number][]) {
  let result: string[] = [];
  arr.forEach(([element]) => {
    result.push(element);
  })
  return result;
}
```

Note that I use Destructuring assignment to get first element.

Comment: Could you explain the syntax arr: [string, number][] please?  Is that just saying let arr be an array of arrays containing [string, number]?

Comment: I update an answer. That is the way to define an array of arrays. And it specifically says that all arrays inside an array have 2 elements first as string and second as a number

Answer (score 3):

The solution mentioned above is fine but we can easily **write the same code with the ES6 map function** if you carefully look at the question they are saying it takes an array of [names and ages] so it means [[name1,age1], [name2,age2] .........]

so the return type should be [string, number][]

This is my approach :

```
function names(namesAndAges: [string,number][]): string[] {
  return namesAndAges.map(nameAndAge => nameAndAge[0]);
}
```

Hope it helps it is just using map function and returning only the names from name and age array

Comment: Hey Navin. Do you know why the types go in the first array? I've always thought of it as an 'array of arrays', so would have put the types in the second pair of brackets